# How to design a counter with reset in simulink and stateflow

Tags: matlab, simulink, stateflow

Design a counter that decrements and increments by 1 with rest option which means it rests to zero and starts the counting from one.this problem should be done using both simulink and stateflow.

Comment: What is the counter supposed to count (i.e. when is it supposed to decrement and when is it supposed to decrement)? And under which condition is it supposed to reset? Please put a little bit more effort into asking a complete question that we can answer.

Comment: Show us what you have tried rather than just posting your homework.